# Why my CSS style won't show onthe flask app

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I just finished my first Flask App, now I want to add CSS to the HTML templates. I am doing everything as I read from the tutorials on TutorialPoint and W3Schools. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

app.py

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form=forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user=models.User.get(models.User.email==form.email.data)
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            flash(" Greshka so email ili pass", "error")
        else:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                flash("Vie se logiravte", "success")
                return redirect(url_for("post"))
            else:
                flash("Greshka so email ili pass", "error")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

login.html

```html
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dizajn.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
{% from 'macro.html' import render_field %}

{% block content%}
<h4>Dobrdojdovte</h4>
<form method="POST" action="" class="pole">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ render_field(field) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Login!</button>
</form>
<a href="register">Nov korisnik?</a>
{% endblock %}
```

dizajn.css

```css
.pole{
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px
    height: 20px;

}
h4{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

When I reload the page `<h4>` is styled but the forms are not. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you lose your `<head>` while pasting your code into SO?

Comment: Yes, there is opening ```<head>``` tag in the file

Comment: h4 is not styled directly, only after a reload ? if you inspect the block in the browser, what property can you see ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify all your pages are getting 200 reponse code in networking tab next to console. If it is not working manually add absolute of css page by inspecting your link elements. If both are not working try to check syntax error in your css page such as missing semicolon, curly bracketd etc.

Comment: It works when I add it from the console, but the console gives a warning " Found 2 elements with non-unique id #csrf_token:".What does that mean?

Comment: Take source code of your page and search for csrf_token. Verify the html source code, probably there will be two html elements  (say div) have same id csrf_token. Take an example of classroom with students where each student have unique id and you can apply styles whole students with class name, but if you want to style particular one you want to style with student id. I means id should be unique.